# anchor's instruction create account but with CPI?

Tags: anchor, cpi

i have created an anchor method that needs an escrow account. When i use this method, the escrow account is created with `instructions: [ await program.account.escrowAccount.createInstruction(escrow), ],`
and it works well.
Althought, now, i need to call the same method but from another program. How can i add this instruction to create the escrow account from another program ?
Thanks !